# Modulo Arithmetic - Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Solve the linear congurence $17x\equiv 3(\mod{2*3*5*7})$ by solving the system:**

$17x\equiv 3(\mod{2})$

- For this one, I simplified to $x\equiv 1(\mod{2})$. Let this $x=5$.

$17x\equiv 3(\mod{3})$

- For this one, I simplified to $x\equiv 0(\mod{3})$. Let this $x=3$.

$17x\equiv 3(\mod{5})$

- For this one, I simplified to $2x\equiv 3(\mod{5})$, then again to $2x\equiv -2(\mod{5})$ and once more to $x\equiv -1(\mod{5})$.Let this $x=9$.

$17x\equiv 3(\mod{7})$

- For this one, I simplified to $3x\equiv 3(\mod{7})$, then again to $x\equiv 1(\mod{7})$. Let this $x=8$.

After all of this, I plugged it into the equation $$x\equiv a_1N_1x_1 + a_2N_2x_2 + a_3N_3x_3 + a_4N_4x_4 (\mod 210)$$

In the equation above, $N_1=105$, $N_2=70$, $N_3=42$, $N_4=30$. Also, $a_1=1$, $a_2=0$, $a_3=-1$ and $a_4=1$.

And I'm coming to $x\equiv177(\mod 210)$, and I should be coming to  $x\equiv99(\mod 210)$. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? It's driving me crazy.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think it's just arithmetic; can you check that or post the arithmetic?

Comment: I thought it was too, and I swear I've gone over it a ton. I'll edit and include as much as I can.

Comment: Can you show your work on how you got your values for the a's?

Comment: From $17x\equiv3(\mod3)$ implying $17x\equiv0(\mod3)$...is that wrong?

Comment: I have not seen this formula before, but I think I know what it's doing:  It's setting the value of $x$ so that it satisfies all of the mods.  To do this, it uses one term for each mod, and it makes sure the other addends don't affect the sum by making them 0; for example, for mod 2, multiplying each of the factors by the Ns makes them 0 mod 2, and we want the first term to be congruent to $x$ mod 2.  To do this, we want $a_1$ to be the multiplicative inverse of $N_1$ mod 2.  Do you follow what I am saying?

Comment: Oh yes!! I was skipping an entire step - I think I need to set $N_1x\equiv1(\mod2)$ essentially and solve for that $x$ instead - right?

Comment: Not quite; do you think it would be beneficial to move this to chat?

Comment: I just got it!! I went with what I mentioned in my last comment and went back to the formula with the new $x_{i's}$. So I'm good - I saw where I was going wrong, based on class notes and examples. Thank you for steering me in the right direction and noticing something was off :)

Comment: I got $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = (1,1,-2,-3)$ so that $\sum{a_i N_i} = 105 + 70 - 84 - 90 = 1$. With your numbers, $\sum{a_i N_i} = 105 - 42 + 30 = 93$..

Answer (score 1):

To compute $a_1 N_1$:
\begin{align}
   a_1 N_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
   105 a_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
   a_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
\hline
   a_1 N_1 &= 105
\end{align}

To compute $a_2 N_2$:
\begin{align}
   a_2 N_2 &\equiv 1 \pmod 3\\
   70 a_2 &\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
   a_2 &\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
\hline
   a_2 N_2 &= 70
\end{align}

To compute $a_3 N_3$:
\begin{align}
   a_3 N_3 &\equiv 1 \pmod 5\\
   42 a_3 &\equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
   2  a_3 &\equiv 1 \pmod 5 \\
   a_3 &\equiv -2 \pmod 5 \\
\hline
   a_2 N_2 &= -84
\end{align}

To compute $a_4 N_4$:
\begin{align}
   a_4 N_4 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7\\
   30 a_4 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
   2  a_4 &\equiv 1 \pmod 7 \\
   a_3 &\equiv -3 \pmod 5 \\
\hline
   a_2 N_2 &= -90
\end{align}

As a check, you must have $\sum a_i N_i \equiv 1 \pmod {210}$ where $210 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7$. Using the numbers above, you get $105 + 70  - 84 - 90 = 175 - 174 = 1$.

Your answer is 
\begin{align}
   x
   &\equiv 105(5) + 70(3) -  84(9) - 90(8) \pmod{210} \\
   &\equiv 525 + 210 - 756 - 720 \pmod{210} \\
   &\equiv 105 + 0 - 126 - 90 \pmod{210} \\
   &\equiv 105 - 216 \pmod{210} \\
   &\equiv 105 - 6 \pmod{210} \\
   &\equiv 99 \pmod{210}
\end{align}

To check we compute  $17(99) = 1683 = 3 \pmod{210}$

### Comment

You solved $17x_1 \equiv 3 \pmod 2$ and got $x_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. You decided to let $x_1 = 5$. This means you had to compute $105(5) = 525$ instead of $(105)(1) = 105$. Since $525 \equiv 105 \pmod{210}$, you can use either number; but, if you are going to do your computations by hand, why would you choose a more complicated number?

Answer (score 0):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

has the notation I am about to use.

As you have computed correctly, $a_i ={1,0,-1,1}$ and $M/m_i= {105,70,42,30}$ (in order), now you must compute $b_i$ as the page describes. These are $b_i =1,1,3,4$ yielding $x \equiv 105*1*1 +0 -1*3*42 +1*30*4 = 99$ as desired.